# Creating structure for geometry data

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

I want to draw multiple polygons in one buffer, here is my conception of how I think it should work, but it does not.
This is what I have:

```
GLuint VertexArrayID; 
GLuint vao;
GLuint program;

typedef struct object{
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint numVertices;
} object;

object objects[MAX_VERTEX_COUNT];
```

Here I create VBO:

```
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexArrayID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * vertex_count * sizeof(float), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(data), data);
    glUseProgram(program);
    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertex_count);
```

And I made loop like that, but I think, when I put vao in objects[i].vao, every time when I came through that loop, it does the same without this loop, but I am not sure.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        objects[i].vao = vao;
        glBindVertexArray(objects[i].vao);
        objects[i].numVertices = vertex_count;
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, objects[i].numVertices);
    }

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: How is `VertexArrayID` initialized? I don't see any `glGenBuffers` getting called. For every loop you seem to be using just a VAO and no VBO.

Comment: I'd recommend that you go through [a good tutorial](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/01-getting-started-in-xcode-and-visual-cpp) which covers the subject in depth.

Comment: I agree with legends2k I do not see where you are calling glGenBuffers; and also whenever you use a bind call from OpenGL after you populate the vao, vbo you need to unbind them with a call as such: glBindVertexArray( 0 ); This is what allows the vertex array and buffer objects to be stopped. I'll post a snippet from my Shader Engine into an answer: it is too large of a project to post everything for a full build; but to show you the binding and unbinding calls it should serve enough as a good reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have an Image2D class object that is used to render basic 2D Images that works with my GUI hierarchy. My Shader Engine is quite large for I have a system to manage Shaders using template types. It also uses a Batch Process and all of my Assets that are loaded into memory are saved into a Storage class that handles the clean up of their memory footprint. It is too large of a project to show everything necessary to be able to compile a working program, but here is an example of a generated renderable object from within my ShaderEngine.

**Image2d.h**

```
class Image2d : public VisualMko {
private:
    TextureInfo m_textureInfo;

    // --- Only For Version 1.0 ---
    // VBO                       //
    unsigned m_vboTexture;       //
    unsigned m_vboPosition;      //
    unsigned m_vboIndices;       //
    //                           //
    // VAO                       //
    unsigned m_vao;              //
    // ------------------------- //

    // version 2.0 variables below
    glm::vec2   m_offsetPosition;

public:
    Image2d( float fWidth, float fHeight, TextureInfo::FilterQuality filterQuality, bool generateMipMap, const std::string& strTextureFilename, const std::string& strId );
    Image2d( const glm::uvec2& origin, const glm::uvec2& size, const std::string& strTextureFilename, const std::string& strId = std::string() );
    virtual ~Image2d();

    void    setOffsetPosition( const glm::vec2& offset );

    virtual void clearTextureInfos() override;

    void render() override;

    TextureInfo getTextureInfo() const;
    void        setTextureInfo( const TextureInfo& textureInfo );

private:
    Image2d( const Image2d& c ); // Not Implemented
    Image2d& operator=( const Image2d& c );

}; // Image2d    

} // namespace vmk

#endif // IMAGE2D_H
```

**Image2d.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Image2d.h"

#include "AssetStorage.h"
#include "ShaderManager.h" // Only Needed For Version 1.0
#include "TextureFileReader.h"

namespace vmk {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Image2d()
// Creates A Rectangular 2D Imgae Of The Size Specified And Stores It In A
// Vertex Array Object For Rendering. The Surface Verts Are Defined Like:
//        width
//      <------->
//      v0 --- v2  ^
//      :    /  :  | height
//      :  /    :  |
//      v1 --- v3  v
//
Image2d::Image2d( float fWidth, float fHeight, TextureInfo::FilterQuality filterQuality, bool generateMipMap, const std::string& strTextureFilename, const std::string& strId ) :
VisualMko( glm::uvec2(), strId ),
m_vboTexture( 0 ),
m_vboPosition( 0 ),
m_vboIndices( 0 ),
m_vao( 0 ) {
    if ( fWidth <= 0 || fHeight <= 0 ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid image size (" << fWidth << "," << fHeight << ") must be more then 0 in each dimension.";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    // Save TextureID
    TextureFileReader textureFileReader( strTextureFilename );
    m_textureInfo = textureFileReader.getOrCreateTextureInfo( filterQuality, generateMipMap, false );

    // Define Texture Coordinates
    std::vector<float> vTextureCoordinates;
    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 0.0f );
    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 1.0f );

    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 0.0f );
    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 0.0f );

    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 1.0f );
    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 1.0f );

    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 1.0f );
    vTextureCoordinates.push_back( 0.0f );

    // Define Vertex Positions (x,y,z)
    std::vector<float> vVertexPositions;
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( fHeight );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );

    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );

    vVertexPositions.push_back( fWidth );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( fHeight );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );

    vVertexPositions.push_back( fWidth );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );
    vVertexPositions.push_back( 0.0f );

    // Define 2 Triangle Faces
    std::vector<unsigned char> vIndices;
    vIndices.push_back( 0 );
    vIndices.push_back( 1 );
    vIndices.push_back( 2 );
    vIndices.push_back( 3 );

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &m_vao );
    glBindVertexArray( m_vao ); // Start Array

    m_pShaderManager->setAttribute( A_COLOR, COLOR_WHITE );

    // Create Position Buffer And Store On Video Card
    glGenBuffers( 1, &m_vboPosition );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboPosition );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vVertexPositions.size() * sizeof( vVertexPositions[0] ), &vVertexPositions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    m_pShaderManager->enableAttribute( A_POSITION );

    // Create Texture Coordinate Buffer
    glGenBuffers( 1, &m_vboTexture );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboTexture );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vTextureCoordinates.size() * sizeof( vTextureCoordinates[0] ), &vTextureCoordinates[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    m_pShaderManager->enableAttribute( A_TEXTURE_COORD0 );

    // Create Index Buffer
    glGenBuffers( 1, &m_vboIndices );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIndices );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vIndices.size() * sizeof( vIndices[0] ), &vIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 ); // Stop Array

    // Disable Attribute Pointers
    m_pShaderManager->disableAttribute( A_POSITION );
    m_pShaderManager->disableAttribute( A_TEXTURE_COORD0 );

    // THIS MUST BE AFTER: Vertex Array Buffer Is Unbound!
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 ); // Stop Buffer Index
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 ); // Stop Buffer

} // Image2d - v1.0

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Image2d()
Image2d::Image2d( const glm::uvec2& origin, const glm::uvec2& size, const std::string& strTextureFilename, const std::string& strId ) :
VisualMko( size, strId ),
m_vboTexture( 0 ),
m_vboPosition( 0 ),
m_vboIndices( 0 ),
m_vao( 0 ) {
    m_version = 2;

    TextureFileReader textureFileReader( strTextureFilename );
    m_textureInfo = textureFileReader.getOrCreateTextureInfo( TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE, false, false );
    m_config.uTextureId = m_textureInfo.uTextureId;

    if ( 0 == m_textureInfo.size.x || 0 == m_textureInfo.size.y ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " size of " << strTextureFilename << " is invalid " << m_textureInfo.size;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    // Verify Image Fits Inside Texture
    if ( m_textureInfo.size.x < size.x + origin.x || m_textureInfo.size.y < size.y + origin.y ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " " << strTextureFilename << " size is " << m_textureInfo.size
            << " which is too small for an image that is " << size
            << " pixels in size, with an origin point set at " << origin ;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    glm::vec2 textureCoordScaleFactor( 1.0f / static_cast<float>( m_textureInfo.size.x ),
        1.0f / static_cast<float>( m_textureInfo.size.y ) );

    glm::vec2 texCoordBottomLeft = glm::vec2( textureCoordScaleFactor.x * origin.x,
                                              textureCoordScaleFactor.y * ( m_textureInfo.size.y - origin.y - size.y ) );
    glm::vec2 texCoordTopRight   = glm::vec2( textureCoordScaleFactor.x * ( origin.x + size.x ),
                                              textureCoordScaleFactor.y * (m_textureInfo.size.y - origin.y ) );

    // Set Colors And Texture Coordinates (Position Will Be Updated In Render Function
    m_vVertices.push_back( GuiVertex( glm::vec2(), COLOR_WHITE, glm::vec2( texCoordBottomLeft.x, texCoordTopRight.y ) ) );
    m_vVertices.push_back( GuiVertex( glm::vec2(), COLOR_WHITE, glm::vec2( texCoordBottomLeft.x, texCoordBottomLeft.y ) ) );
    m_vVertices.push_back( GuiVertex( glm::vec2(), COLOR_WHITE, glm::vec2( texCoordTopRight.x,   texCoordTopRight.y ) ) );
    m_vVertices.push_back( GuiVertex( glm::vec2(), COLOR_WHITE, glm::vec2( texCoordTopRight.x,   texCoordBottomLeft.y ) ) );

} // Image2d() - v2.0

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~Image2d()
Image2d::~Image2d() {
    if ( 1 == m_version ) {
        // Destroy Objects
        if ( m_vboTexture != 0 ) {
            glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
            glDeleteBuffers( 1, &m_vboTexture );
            m_vboTexture = 0;
        }
        if ( m_vboPosition != 0 ) {
            glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
            glDeleteBuffers( 1, &m_vboPosition );
            m_vboPosition = 0;
        }
        if ( m_vboIndices != 0 ) {
            glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
            glDeleteBuffers( 1, &m_vboIndices );
            m_vboIndices = 0;
        }
        if ( m_vao != 0 ) {
            glBindVertexArray( 0 );
            glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &m_vao );
            m_vao = 0;
        }
    }
} // Image2d

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setOffsetPosition()
void Image2d::setOffsetPosition( const glm::vec2& offset ) {
    if ( offset.x != m_offsetPosition.x || offset.y != m_offsetPosition.y ) {
        m_offsetPosition = offset;
        m_transformMatrix.updateTranslation = true;
    }
} // setOffsetPosition

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// clearTextureInfos()
void Image2d::clearTextureInfos() {
    if ( m_pAssetStorage->removeTextureInfo( m_textureInfo.uTextureId ) ) {
        m_textureInfo = TextureInfo();
    }
} // clearTextureInfos

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// render()
void Image2d::render() {
    if ( 1 == m_version ) {
        m_pShaderManager->setTexture( 0, U_TEXTURE0_SAMPLER_2D, m_textureInfo.uTextureId );

        glBindVertexArray( m_vao );
        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr );
        glBindVertexArray( 0 );
    } else {
        // Version 2.0
        // Update Vertices
        if ( m_transformMatrix.updateTranslation || m_transformMatrix.updateScale || m_transformMatrix.updateRotation ) {
            m_transformMatrix.updateTranslation = m_transformMatrix.updateScale = m_transformMatrix.updateRotation = false;

            // Order Of Operations Matter Here!
            glm::mat4 matrix; // identity

            if ( m_transformMatrix.hasTranslation ) {
                matrix[3][0] = m_transformMatrix.translation.x;
                matrix[3][1] = m_transformMatrix.translation.y;
            }

            if ( m_transformMatrix.hasRotation ) {
                matrix = glm::rotate( matrix, m_transformMatrix.fRotationAngleDegrees, glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f ) );
            }

            if ( m_transformMatrix.hasScale ) {
                matrix = matrix * glm::mat4( m_transformMatrix.scale.x,                       0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                   0.0f, m_transformMatrix.scale.y, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                   0.0f,                      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                                                   0.0f,                      0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
            }

            // Center Offset
            if ( m_offsetPosition.x != 0 || m_offsetPosition.y != 0 ) {
                matrix = glm::translate( matrix, glm::vec3( -m_offsetPosition.x, -m_offsetPosition.y, 0.0f ) );
            }

            // Apply Transformation To All 4 Vertices
            m_vVertices[0].position = glm::vec2( matrix * glm::vec4(        0,        0, 0, 1.0f ) );
            m_vVertices[1].position = glm::vec2( matrix * glm::vec4(        0, m_size.y, 0, 1.0f ) );
            m_vVertices[2].position = glm::vec2( matrix * glm::vec4( m_size.x,        0, 0, 1.0f ) );
            m_vVertices[3].position = glm::vec2( matrix * glm::vec4( m_size.x, m_size.y, 0, 1.0f ) );
        }
        renderBatch();
    }
} // render

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getTextureInfos()
TextureInfo Image2d::getTextureInfo() const {
    return m_textureInfo;
} // getTextureInfo

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setTextureInfo()
void Image2d::setTextureInfo( const TextureInfo& textureInfo ) {
    m_textureInfo = textureInfo;
} // setTextureInfo

} // namespace vmk
```

Now this class has two constructors which will get called depending on which version of the Image2d is being used. If I remember correctly version 1 does not use the BatchManager or Batch Process while version 2 does. If you look at the 1st Constructor. `glBindVertexArray( 0 );` and `glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );` `glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );` methods are called to stop the arrays and buffers. In render call in the first section of the if statement again we call `glBindVertexArray( 0 );` to stop the array.

If you look at the destructor version 2 does not get cleaned up due to the fact that it is being used through the BatchManager and everything that is used through the BatchManager is automatically cleaned up and handled by my AssetStorage class. However, since version 1 of this class does not use the BatchManager it has to clean itself up and you can see the calls to `glBindBuffer( BUFFER_ENUMERATED_TYPE, 0 );` followed by a `glDeleteBuffers(...);` call then setting the VBOs and VAO to 0.

If you would like to know more about this and how to successfully build a 3D Graphics ShaderEngine using modern OpenGL visit http://www.marekknows.com for this is where I have learned how to successfully use OpenGL. These works are not of my own design, but everything in this Engine was manually typed and debugged by following Marek's video tutorials.